# Format the output of a CMD command

Tags: windows, batch-file

Hi I'm executing this bat in a windows environment

```
for /f "usebackq" %%i in (hostname) DO SET host=%%i
for /R c:\Users\ %%G IN (*.jpg) DO (
echo %host% >> output.txt
certutil -hashfile "%%G" MD5)
```

And I'm getting this output

```
Hostame
Hahs MD5 of the file <file> is
<hash>
CertUtil: -hashfile command executed
```

I need help so I can format the output like:

```
<hostname>,,<File>,,<hash>
```

Comment: So do what you are doing with the FOR command when capturing the output of the hostname.  Put your certutil command into a `FOR /F` command and parse the output.  Then output everything to our log file.

Comment: You do realize you could just use the environmental variable %computername% instead of executing the hostname command.

Comment: You are missing the back quotes around hostname.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    for /f "delims=" %%a in ('hostname') do set "host=%%a"

    >output.txt (
        for %%z in (*.jpg) do for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
            certutil -hashfile "%%z" MD5 ^| find /v ":"
        ') do echo %host%,,%%z,,%%a
    )
```

You can use the `%computername%` instead of execute `hostname` to retrieve the machine name, but:

- The first `for /f` to execute the `hostname` command now includes a `delims=` clause to ensure (I think this is not needed, but just to be sure) there will be no splitting on spaces in the machine name. Also, the command to execute is enclosed in single quotes
- The inner `for /f` will process the output of the `certutil` command. `delims=` is also included to retrieve the full MD5 line (in this case is a requirement as the output is a separate list of two hex characters). The output of the `cerutil -hashfile` also includes informative lines that are removed piping the output to a `find` command to remove lines with a colon (present in informative lines and not in the hash)
- The full `for %%z` that iterates the files and the inner `for /f` that executes `certutil` have been redirected to the output file. This will open the output file only once, sending to it all the output of the inner commands sent to standard output stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I just added /R c:\Users for the %%z for and worked perfectly